# Cloudfoundry- don't have python runtime

Tags: cloud-foundry

this website says cloudfoundry have already supproted python runtimes
but when I type `vmc runtimes` , it doesn't show python

Does anyone know what's going on?

It would be very appreciated if you can help
thanks.

Comment: Which website are you referring to? CloudFoundry is a two sided project: There is cloudfoundry.org which is the opensource bits, where the code resides on github. You can find there that there is support for python, thanks to ActiveState/Stackato. OTOH, cloudfoundry.com is VMware hosting *a* CloudFoundry installation with *some* runtimes and you are correct that python is not currently on the list. If you follow the instructions for builing what is called "dev_setup", you can get python support.

Comment: sorry I forgot to paste the website link up here, but I follow https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap  to install my cloudfoundry, and I still can't push python apps to my xxx.vcap.me, it says "can't detect the application type"(something like that..)
do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I haven't done that in a while, and can't remember if I got python support at the time, but: There are different ways to install a custom CloudFoundry, thanks to the automated script called "dev_setup" ( https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/tree/master/dev_setup).

This is what is explained here ( https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap) and I suspect this is what you have been following, given your previous comments.

Now, here is the thing: There are different options related to what should be deployed (the "`-c`" command line switch) so you may want to have a look at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/tree/master/dev_setup/deployments. In particular, there is a "all" deployment model that brings in the whole kitchen sink, so you can try this and confirm that you get python support. Also, have a look at the `custom_runtimes` thing in `samples`, this may be of interest to you.

As stated above, I haven't done this in a while, so I hope I'm on the right track here.

Comment: Thanks, @ebottard, I'll take a look on what you mention about, hope that's what I need

Comment: Hi Arvin, FYI I just did a fresh vanilla install of dev_setup as explained here https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap and got python support. So you may want to check your install